# How many bytes contain exactly two 1s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I know the answer is $C(8,2)$, but I was confused as to why the answer wouldn't be $P(8,2)$? Doesn't the order of the 0s and 1s matter? For example: 10010000 is different than 10100000, so don't we have to consider every possible permutation of the zeros and the two ones?

Comment: As a quick way to check yourself, if a byte were, say, two characters long we have would the possible options $00, 01, 10, 11.$ This essentially comes down to the fact you don't want to double count

Comment: The order refers to the labels. Because all of them are $1$ there is no order associated.

Comment: We have to consider every possible *choice* of the positions of the six zeros and the two ones

Comment: $00000011$ isn't different than $00000011$ (I swapped the two $1$'s).

Comment: You need to specify the locations of the two 1's. Clearly this can be done in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways.

Comment: Right, I think I get it now. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. But, combinations take care of that. There are $8!$ ways to permute the symbols in a byte. If 2 are ones interchanging them ( aka permuting indistinguishable things), doesn't change the combination placement. Same with interchanging the six 0's . So, we have:$$\frac{8!}{2!6!}=\binom{8}{2}$$ ways.